# Docker redis container instantly exits

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new with docker.
This is my dosker-compose.yml. Php and nginx containers are running, but redis is instantly exits.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
#### PHP-FPM ##############################################
    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: ./docker/php
            dockerfile: php-fpm.docker
        volumes:
            - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}/backend/api:/var/www/html
        environment:
            - REDIS_PASSWORD=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
            - REDIS_HOST=${REDIS_HOST}
            - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
        depends_on:
            - redis
        links:
            - redis
        expose:
            - 9000


### REDIS ##############################################
    redis:
        image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
        environment:
            - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
        ports:
            - ${REDIS_PORT}:6379
        volumes:
            - ${DOCKER_STORAGE_REDIS}:/bitnami/redis/data
```

My yml file looks like in bitnami:latest, can you tell me please what is miss?
And this is .env file content

```
### APP ################################################
APP_CODE_PATH_HOST=./src

### Redis #############################################
REDIS_PORT=63800
REDIS_HOST=redis

### DOCKER storage ####################################
DOCKER_STORAGE_REDIS=./storage/redis
```

Comment: It seems there is no problem, to evaluate if i am missing something, i used your configuration file, only the redis part and tried. Everything works just fine. There must be something else. Why do you use links actually ?

Comment: is it a bad practice to use links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out problem was in rights, redis couldn't get acess to folders on my machine, chmod 777 ./storage/redis solved it